# Elementary Riemann curvature calculation

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

Suppose I have a surface like $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$. The gradient of this surface is $(2x, 2y)$. I understand the Riemann curvature of this surface is like the commutator of 2nd derivatives, which here is obviously $0$. A really naive question is, how does this map onto the actual idea of the curvature of this surface, which increases by $2$ in any $x$ or $y$ direction? There is an acceleration along curves, even if that kind of lengthening is in a "straight" direction ... so I'm a little confused about how there is no curvature.

What I'm really trying to get to the bottom of is how we can understand lack of commuting 2nd derivatives as a force in general relativity. I get failing to parallel transport around a curve, and there should definitely be loops like that on the surface of $f(x, y)$, which is kind of like a gently curving slope. Though I am still calculating it as $0$. Sorry for the elementary question, but any help in understanding **why** the calculated curvature of $f(x, y)$ is not the naive curving on the surface would be really great.

Comment: What curvature are you trying to calculate exactly and what you mean by commutator of 2nd derivatives?

Comment: Well, as I say, Im having trouble wrapping my head around two ideas of curvature that seem to conflict. By commutator of 2nd derivatives I mean the definition of the riemann curvature. If we send a vector (in the gradient?) around a loop, the change in this vector is the curvature. We can measure it by $\partial_u v - \partial_v u$ + a more complicated term that Im not interested in

Comment: I guess that should actually be $\nabla_u \nabla_v X - \nabla_v \nabla_u X$ for a vector $X$ with components named $\rho$

Comment: The way you differentiate a vectorfield on a surface is to take the usual derivative in $\mathbb R^3$ and then apply an orthogonal projection onto the corresponding tangent spaces. It is this kind of differentiation the Riemann curvature tensor talks about.

Comment: The surface $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ is the upper hemisphere in two dimensions. It is best parametrized with polar coordinates. [This site](http://einsteinrelativelyeasy.com/index.php/general-relativity/70-the-riemann-curvature-tensor-for-the-surface-of-a-sphere) does all the calculations.

Comment: @ClaraB. would you mind elaborating on that? it seems like an important distinction, but I don't think I understand what you're getting at

Comment: @KurtG. thanks so much for the resource, I'll take a look :-)

Comment: @rage_man : in fact your surface is *not* the hemisphere. Nevertheless the resource is always good. I think I can also write a very elementary answer to your question when we look at curvature in $1D\,.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking (rightfully) what the second derivative of a function has to do with curvature in a geometric sense. Let's keep the following  principles in mind:

- Riemannian curvature measures the rate of change of the ***direction in the tangent space*** of a tangential vector to the manifold.
- when the manifold is at least $2D$ we can move between two points along different curves and that's what makes the concept of Riemannian curvature a bit difficult. Parallel transport is needed to understand this.
- the tangent spaces at a one-dimensional curve are all one dimensional. A vector cannot change its direction in a tangent space (there is no Riemannian curvature). However, we can ask how a vector changes its direction in the ***ambient space*** the curve lives in.

Let's look at this $1D$ case in more detail.

Example 1. $f(x)=x^2\,.$ This one-dimensional curve is a parabola in ambient space $\mathbb R^2\,.$ It can be parametrized by
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}x\\x^2\end{matrix}\right)\,,\quad\text{ point on curve }\,.
$$
The derivative w.r.t. $x$ of this vector is the tangent vector to the curve at its point with parameter $x\,:$
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}1\\2x\end{matrix}\right)\,,\quad\text{ tangent vector to the curve }\,.
$$
Because we are only interested in the ***direction*** of the tangent vector let's switch to the angle $\alpha$ between the vector and the $x$ axis:
$$
\alpha=\arctan(2x)\,.
$$
The rate of change of this direction when $x$ varies is (if I am not mistaken)
$$
\frac{d\alpha}{dx}=\cos^2(\arctan 2x)\,.
$$
At $x=0$ this naive curvature is one and decreses to zero when $x^2$ gets very large. That's intuitively clear as the parabola looks pretty much like a straight line when $x^2$ is very large.

Example 2. $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}\,.$ This is the upper part of a circle with radius one. We expect this to have constant curvature. To see that this is in fact the case it is better to parametrize the curve in polar coordinates:
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}\cos\theta\\\sin\theta\end{matrix}\right)\,,\quad\text{ point on curve }\,,\quad
\left(\begin{matrix}-\sin\theta\\\cos\theta\end{matrix}\right)\,,\quad\text{ tangent vector to the curve }\,.
$$
The angle between the tangent vector and the $x$ axis is
$$
\alpha=\theta+\frac{\pi}{2}\,.
$$
Its rate of change is constant - as expected.

Comment: So this records very similar information as $R(X,Y)Z$, in other words, it acts to change a vector $Z$ by some amount? It isn't exactly the same because we've changed our perspective from the curve/surface to the ambient space... and I definitely still calculate $0$ for the riemann curvature of a paraboloid... if I'm reading this right, it's starting to make sense for me

Comment: But, I'm actually not sure my calculation is correct, so maybe I'm a little more confused than I thought

Comment: Do you have any ideas about how might I relate your approach to the equation $\nabla_X \nabla_Y Z - \nabla_Y \nabla_X Z$, the one I mentioned above? Or something like $\partial_k\Gamma_j - \partial_j \Gamma_k$, in terms of christoffel symbols?

Comment: Sorry if my approach was confusing. Bullet number three in my answer is the reason why that simple $1D$ calculation has in fact little to do with Riemann curvature. To understand the latter you may probably wanto to start with [parallel transport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_transport).