# Relationship between convex functions and surfaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

Suppose you have a convex function $f(x,y,z)$, e.g., $x^2+y^2-z$, and you create the corresponding surface $f(x,y,z)=0$. If you look at surface curves, e.g, curves of constant  $z$ or constant azimuthal polar angle, does the convexity of $f(x,y,z)$ tell you anything about whether the curves on the surface are convex and visa versa? If so, what does it tell you and what might be some useful references on this subject?

Good questions.  I'll try to be more specific.  In terms of polar coordinates {$\rho$, $\theta$, $z$}, I am primary interested in the curves  $\phi$($z$) = $\rho$ ($z$, $\theta_0$) and $\psi$ = $\rho$($z_0$,  $\theta$), where $\theta_0$ and  $z_0$  are constants.  For the former, I would like to know if $\phi$''$\leq 0$ and for the latter if  $\psi^2$+2 $\psi '^2$ - $\psi \psi ``$ $\geq 0$.

Comment: The curve of constant $z$ is the circle with radius $z$. A circle is not a convex set. A one dimensional curve is convex if and only if it is a straight line.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I'm sorry.  I'm really asking about the curvature of the surface curves.  Does that help?

Comment: There are many ways to define curvature. Riemannian curvature of a one dimensional curve is zero. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4369211/elementary-riemann-curvature-calculation/4370382#4370382) About other types of curvature that have been developed for plane curves resp. (in your case) curves in space you can learn [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Space_curves).

Comment: Or, did you mean by curvature the second derivative of the curve? Please make a choice.

Comment: Curves on a surface can be as wobbly as they wish. Do you have specific curves in mind?

Comment: The curve is the boundary of the convex set $\{(x,y,z): \ f(x,y,z) \le c\}$.